# How to save excel file with openpyxl and preserve pivot table as is?

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table, openpyxl

I have an excel file - one sheet is used for writing data with python, other sheet contains pivot table. I want to keep pivot table exactly the same as source file.

The problem is that after saving new workbook with openpyxl I open excel file and refresh pivot table, it loses 'Field settings..' -> 'Repeat items label' checkbox and I need to manually turn it on each time. That is not very efficient, I would rather solve this with python.
Sample file has it checked, but checkbox seems to disappear after saving new file with openpyxl.

[image: Image from Excel workbook]

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import date
import os

sample_file_path = Path('sample_excel.xlsx')   # source excel
result_folder_path = Path('results')

wb = load_workbook(sample_file_path)
ws = wb["t_mm"]  # worksheet with pivot table I want to preserve as is

# some manipulations to other worksheet 

xlsx_filename = "test_my_file_%s.xlsx" % date.today().strftime('%d%m%Y')
completename = os.path.join(result_folder_path, xlsx_filename)
wb.save(completename)
```

I read the documentation https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.pivot.table.html, but couldn't figure out how to keep that checkbox. I am not excel or pivot table expert. I think this is the parameter I need "showMultipleLabel=True", but from docs I understand that it's "True" by default, so my chekbox should remain intact. Maybe other parameter?

Comment: off-topic - from experience I faced a lot of issues with Pivot tables and Openpyxl. Finally, I always keep all pivot tables in one workbook and all the data in another. python only works on the data workbook and the pivot tables remain intact.

Comment: @shoaib30 Thank you for advice. I also ended up splitting data file from pivot file for this project.